# How can i understand the order of a recursive function?

Tags: java, recursion

```
// Driver Code
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int test = 3;
    printFun(test);
}
```

```
static void printFun(int test) {         
     if (test < 1)
        return;
    else {
        System.out.printf("%d ", test);
        printFun(test - 1); // statement 2
        System.out.printf("%d ", test);
        return;
    }
}
```

In this piece of code taken from GeeksforGeeks. There is something that I couldn't understand, It writes `3 2 1 1 2 3` and the recursive function is allocated in stacks. So it calls the `statement2` before the second `printf`, does this mean it firstly writes the recursive function and skips the second `printf` until the base case is satisfied and then prints the second `printf`. I couldn't completely understand the order.

Comment: A debugger or pen and paper would be really useful when trying to understand this.

Answer (score 2):

When you call a function, the function runs to completion, then returns. This is the same in a recursive use case, each call completes before returning. But of course each completion means calling another time the same function with a different stack. So this is what happens, in pseudo code:

```
printFun(3)
   print 3
   call printfun(2)
      print 2
      call printfun(1)
         print 1
         call printfun(0)
             return
         print 1
         return
      print 2
      return
   print 3
   return
```

Answer (score 0):

The output is 3 2 1 1 2 3 , the **3 2 1** getting printed as a part of first System.out.println() statement.

**1 2 3** is getting printed as the part of second System.out.println() statement.

- When the value of test=3, it prints 3, and calls the function again
  with the value=2.
- When the value of test=2, it prints 2, and calls
  the function again with the value=1.
- When the value of test=1, it
  prints 1, and calls the function again with the value=0.
- when value
  of test =0, the condition if (test < 1) hold true and it returns.
- but now it comes to complete the part of the function which was below the recursive function call, so 1 gets printed here again.
- similarly, it comes to complete the part of the function below the recursive call of the function, so 2 and 3 gets printed here respectively.